# Operator that gives a permutational symmetry factor

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, bosons, identical-particles

Suppose that we have a system with $N$ bosonic modes, meaning that there is a vacuum state $|0\rangle$ and a set of $N$ pairs of creation-annihilation operators $a_i$ and $a^{\dagger}_i$. When applying a few creation operators to $|0\rangle$ we will have a basis state $|m_1 m_2\ldots m_N\rangle$ (up to a normalization, which is not important for the question.

If some of the numbers $m_1 m_2\ldots m_N$ are equal, then a nontrivial permutation group acts on them. My question is the following: is it possible, and if yes then how, to construct from operators $a_i$ and $a^{\dagger}_i$ a "degeneracy operator" $D$, for which any state $|m_1 m_2\ldots m_N\rangle$ would be an eigenstate with an eigenvalue equal to the order of the permutation group acting on the $m$'s? For example,

$$D|0\rangle = N!|0\rangle$$
$$D|1,0,\ldots 0\rangle = (N-1)!|1,0,\ldots 0\rangle$$
$$D|1,1,0,\ldots 0\rangle = 2(N-2)!|1,1,0,\ldots 0\rangle$$ etc

Comment: What do you find for N=2?

Comment: You don't seem to be asking about the standard [exchange operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_operator)...

Comment: Well, for $N=2$ there are two bosonic modes, and we will have just two possible eigenvalues: for $m_1=m_2$ the eigenvalue is 2, otherwise it is 1

Comment: The vacuum is unique. How do you get a D=2 for vanishing degeneracy? You may need to clarify your question.

Comment: Probably a name "degeneracy" is not a good one. The eigenvalue that I need is a cardinality of a stabilizer of the set $m_1\ldots m_N$ under the action of a permutation group. For the vacuum state $m_1=m_2=\ldots =m_N=0$, so the cardinality of the stabilizer is $N!$. If all $m$'s are different then the stabilizer is just an identity, and the eigenvalue is 1

Comment: Definitely, not probably. You *do* appreciate, gonzo mathematese aside, that the vacuum state is unique, right?

Comment: The vacuum state is unique, no questions about that. However, for the operator that I am looking for it has a biggest possible eigenvalue